# Why environment variables aren't being passed in a single command

Tags: bash, terminal, environment-variables

In bash, I can pass an environment variable to a single command in the following way:

```
KEY=VAL <command>
```

However, I don't understand why the following doesn't work:

```
KEY=VAL echo $KEY
```

While this works:

```
KEY=VAL bash -c 'echo $KEY'
```

i.e. the first one prints a blank line while the other prints "VAL". I'd expect both to print "VAL".

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate I just can't find it at the moment.

Comment: I'd expect so, but couldn't find it either!

Answer (score 2):

Because `KEY=VAL echo $KEY` isn't having `echo` expand the `$KEY` variable.

The current shell is doing that *before* it runs `echo` (or whatever).